# matlab / xcov function

Tags: matlab, autocorrelation

I looked into using `xcov` to calculate auto-covariances of a `Tx1` time series vector. Using `xcov` in the first instance, it seemed as if this function would not devide by `T` as opposed to what the general formula for sample autocovariance would suggest: ?
Can someone confirm whether I need to devide by `T` to get a vector of sample auto-covariances? If I do not devide by `T`, the covariances seem to explode, as more and more terms are added. It is also not clear from the documentation of `xcov`.

For instance:

```
test = randn(10,1);
xcov(test)
```

Best
Marcel

Comment: The documentation is plenty clear about it: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcov.html — the function even has a parameter to control normalization.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the xcov documentation is not really clear. One needs to understand that this function is based on xcorr. According documentation does explain well eventually. This was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The docs I linked say “xcov computes the mean of its inputs, subtracts the mean, and then calls xcorr.” And then “By default, xcov computes raw covariances with no normalization”, and shows the equation it implements. And then it says “The covariance function requires normalization to estimate the function properly. You can control the normalization of the correlation by using the input argument scaleopt.” I think that’s very clear what it does.

Comment: You need to scroll to the bottom of the page, don’t just read the first paragraph.